# How to make Tree View with fix first column width using Vuetify, LiquorTree

Tags: javascript, vue.js, treeview, vuetify.js

[image]

I'm trying to make a nested hierarchy in a table.

I added Vuetify rows and columns width 6|1|1|1|1|1|1 and added tree view in the first column to limit its width to 6 width size.

But now I'm having issues aligning the rest of the columns data to the first column rows.

What would be the best way to have a tree view with a fixed column width and then more columns where additional data can be displayed.
Basically I don't want other columns to move to the right when tree view expands.

This is a high-level of what I'm going for.
[image]